# Avoid severity-level-0 logging in application insights from function app

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app

In my azure solution, I have 1 app service and 2 function apps logging to 1 application insights instance. In a specific environment I want to reduce the logging load, so I wanted to get rid of severity-level-0 logs.

I am currently focusing on one of the function apps, let's call it fa1. The logging statements I add with ILogger as LogDebug do not show up in application insights, as expected. However I can see the following entries in application insights:

- "Poll for function '{name of function in fa1}' on queue '{...}' with ClientRequestId '{...}' found 0 messages in 5 ms."
- "Function '{name of function in fa1}' will wait 60000 ms before polling queue '{...}'."

I also see the following entries, but I do not know which service is generating them:

- "[HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats: EffectiveCores=1, CpuLoadHistory=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), AvgCpuLoad=0, MaxCpuLoad=0"
- "[HostMonitor] Host aggregate CPU load 0"

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Warning",
      "default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.Configure():

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
    loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(key);
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => // Needed for injected ILogger<> to log in AI
{
    var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
    return new TelemetryConfiguration(key);
});
```

I tried `loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(key).SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);` as well.
None of the settings worked, the logging entries mentioned above kept appearing.

Note that I am setting Warning just for testing. At the end I want Information.

What can I do to get rid of those severity-level-0 logging entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the different log categories [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories).

I'd say to reduce logging but keep important information like requests and dependencies set the `Microsoft`, `Worker` and `Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>` categories to LogLevel warning (or none), but keep `Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>.User` and all the others at information. This will remove most logging but keep statistics and the success/failure logs available in the portal.

By doing `loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(key).SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);` you are only changing the loglevel for your the Function category, not the others.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>": "Warning",
      "Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>.User": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Worker": "Warning",
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

The category `Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>` is a tricky one. It generates both useful logs and some noise. Try both Warning and Information as log level and see what best works for you.

**EDIT**
The way you configure the function is wrong. Application Insights is added by Azure Functions automatically ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services)). If you want to directly use a `TelemetryClient` you need to add the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights and that is it.

The default  integration will pick up the configuration from the `host.json` file. Right now you are setting up the logging manually which will ignore the settings since the configuration is not loaded. That is why, for example, the message *Poll for function '{name of function in fa1}' on queue '{...}' with ClientRequestId '{...}' found 0 messages in 5 ms.* that belongs to category *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener* is logged and not filtered. So remove the code you have shown in the question.

Comment: I updated my host.json as yours, but with "Warning" level for all children of "logLevel" for testing purposes. Still I see the logging entries that state in the question, which have severity level 0.

Comment: @JoaoRibeiro extended my answer

Comment: The EDIT really helped! Thanks for that.
I guess I had imported the wrong AI packages. With the package I had before (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights), without the startup code I was not able to log from injected classes with ILogger < MyClass>. That's why I added that startup code. Now with the package you suggested and without the startup code it logs from both functions and injected classes.